# Given an $n\times n$ square matrix $A$, if $C(A) ⊆ N(A)$, then $A^2$ is the $n\times n$ zero matrix. Why is this the case?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a $n\times n$ square matrix $A$, if $C(A) ⊆ N(A)$ - where $C$ and $N$ are respectively the column space and the null space - then $A^2$ is the $n\times n$ zero matrix. Why is this the case?

I would be grateful for a concise explanation of the theorem in the question.

Comment: What is C(A) and N(A)?

Comment: Sorry - the column and null spaces of A respectively.

Comment: What is the relation between Column space of $A$ and the image of $A:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$? Here it might be more helpful to think of $A$ as a linear map rather than just a matrix. What can you say about $A(A(x))$ if the image of $A$ is contained in the null space of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** If $x \in \mathbb R^n$ then $Ax \in C(A) \subseteq N(A)$ and hence 
$$A(Ax)=0$$